# Turn the Firefox location bar into Google search

Tags: firefox, search, address-bar

A few months ago, when I typed something completely irrelevant in the location bar of Firefox, it would take me to Google search results. When I typed something like "facebook", it would take me to www.facebook.com.

I found out that I can turn my location bar into a search box. But this is not what I want as it always goes to the Google search results. I want it to be that way if I type completely irrelevant.

How can I get this feature back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a documented bug in Firefox (9.0.1 at this time) that the "Domain guessing" feature is not working before the search keywords as it should be.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=503171

Comment: Wow, I feel so happy now that It was a bug. How did you even know that!? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the following methods should work when Firefox cannot resolve to a domain:

1. **About:config**
   Set the value of `keyword.URL` to `http://www.google.com/search?q=`
2. **[Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/)**
   Set your DNS servers to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Comment: It is already set to http://www.google.com/search?q= But as I stated in the question, this is not what I want. Since, with this configurations, when I type "facebook", it takes me to the google search results of the keyword "facebook" but I want it to go to www.facebook.com because this is something very known. I want it to take me to google search results when I type, for example, "pencil" as there is no widely known URL correlated with this keyword.

Comment: How about the 2nd method?

Comment: I can't try it because my DNS servers are fixed. If I change, my internet won't work.